# Makefile - Generate Targets from Sources

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to build a growing number of .cpp files with the use of make. They all reside in a subdirectory src/. I want to compile each file into it's own executable, residing in bin/.
This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't work, and since I'm new to make, all the Patterns, Variables etc. make it difficult to pinpoint what gets expanded into what and so on.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

SRC = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
BIN = $(patsubst src/%.cpp,bin/%,$(SRC))

all: $(BIN)

%: scr/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Also, is there a way to show just the contents of BIN for example to allow me to see what is going on?

Comment: There are many conventions in make that it would be wise to follow.  CC is the C compiler, CXX is the C++ compiler, CFLAGS are flags for $(CC), CXXFLAGS are flags for $(CXX), and CPPFLAGS are flags for the preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your final expansion looks like

```
file: scr/bin/file.cpp
```

Why not do this?

```
BIN = $(patsubst src/%.cpp,%,$(SRC))

all: $(addprefix bin/, $(BIN))

bin/% : src/%
    $(GCC) $(FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

I think that works?

As for showing the contents of BIN

```
all: $(addprefix bin/, $(BIN))
    @echo $(BIN)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! At least I wasn't that far off :-)